# fortify: path manipulation in c#

Tags: fortify, path-manipulation

I have the following code snippet:

```
string fileUrl = "Folder1"+jaar+".docx";
getFile(fileUrl);
```

The `jaar parameter which is an int is the current year` and actually comes from the application and it is not an input from the user, however Fortify complains about the fileUrl.

How can I fix this?